# Where is the black hole horizon in ingoing Kerr coordinates?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems, event-horizon, kerr-metric

In ingoing Kerr coordinates, the metric of the [Kerr black hole spacetime](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0622) is:

\begin{equation}
ds^2
=
-\left(1-\frac{2Mr}{\Sigma}\right)dv^2
+\frac{2Mr}{\Sigma}\left(dr-a \mathrm{sin}^2\theta d\phi\right)dv
\\
+\left(1+\frac{2Mr}{\Sigma}\right)\left(dr^2 - 2a\mathrm{sin}^2\theta drd\phi\right)\\
+\Sigma d\theta^2
+\left(r^2+2Ma^2\frac{r \mathrm{sin}^2\theta}{\Sigma} + a^2\right)d\phi^2
\end{equation}
where $\Sigma = r^2 + a^2\mathrm{cos}^2\theta$.

In Boyer-Lindquist coordinates, the two black hole event horizons are located at $r_{\pm}=M\pm\sqrt{M^2-a^2}$. In ingoing Kerr coordinates, it looks like the event horizons are located at
$r_{\pm} = M \pm \sqrt{M^2-a^2\mathrm{cos}^2\theta}$. Is that correct? What I find odd about this relation is that then in the extremal limit ($M=a$), then $r_{\pm}=M\left(1\pm\mathrm{cos}\theta\right)$, so the inner and outer horizons would 'trade places' in terms of which is 'farther away' from the 'origin' $r=0$.

EDIT/ANSWER:

Turns out I wasn't properly computing the radial ingoing/outgoing charactersitics. I need to solve
\begin{equation}
g^{vv}c^2 - 2 g^{vr}c + g^{rr}=0
\end{equation}
which then gives me
\begin{equation}
   c_{\pm}
   =
   \left(1+\frac{2Mr}{\Sigma}\right)^{-1}
   \left(
   -  \frac{2Mr}{\Sigma}
      \pm
      \left[
         \frac{4M^2r^2}{\Sigma^2}
      +  \left(1+\frac{2Mr}{\Sigma}\right)\frac{\Delta}{\Sigma}
      \right]^{1/2}
   \right)
   ,
\end{equation}
where $\Delta=r^2-2mr+a^2$. We see that when $\Delta=0$ all the
characteristics are ingoing/marginally trapped. So the black hole horizon is at the same radial radial coordinate point in both ingoing Kerr and Boyer-Lindquust coordinates.